# HighCharts timezone issues on AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, highcharts, highcharts-ng

I have simple chart with x-axis lables and tooltips,
the date of the months on the tooltips are correct while the months on the x-axis labels is one month behind.

[image: wrong dates on x-axis]

when i change the time zone from GMT+2  US East to UTC-5 the issue resolved.

i also added the following global options useUTC, but it has no affect.

you can see the GMT+2 results in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/liad/uVZ4Z/), when you change your timezone, to utc it will resolved.

```
         Highcharts.setOptions({
            global: {
                useUTC: true
            }
        });
```

---

Any help will be appreciated. (http://jsfiddle.net/liad/uVZ4Z/)

Comment: LEt's consider that example: http://jsfiddle.net/uVZ4Z/1/ I don't know  highcharts-ng directive, but for sure setting `global.useUTC` in chart options won't work. When I use your data, I can see always in tooltip `Tuesday 05:00...` - could you confirm? When you change timezones, do you have different output?

Comment: @PawełFus yes, instead of April i get March on the x-axis you can see the image i attached

Comment: Yes, I can see the image, but I mean if you open my demo do you have the same issue :)

Comment: yes i do, change the timezone on your machine and see it reproduce

Comment: I did changed and it works for me. Doesn't matter if I set -10 or +10, it's always displaying `Apr 00:00` on xAxis and `.. 05:00 ..` in tooltip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `highcharts`, `angularjs` and `highcharts-ng`.
I added the following options (it works for me):

```
Highcharts.setOptions({
    global : {
        useUTC : true,
        timezoneOffset: -2 * 60 //GMT +2
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I don't know how to set global options in highcharts-ng. Is that enough:

```
$scope.chartConfig = {
    global: {
        useUTC: true
    },
```

Anyway, I'm in UTC+2h and I see chart properly, Apr for first column (and the same in a tooltip).

Comment: thanks i did it, no luck with that... it didn't solve the issue

Comment: `useUTC` defaults to true, so it would make sense that this seems to work. It doesn't, though.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this option [is not developed at this moment](https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng/issues/202). So have to use Highcharts object directly.
For example, put that code in any of your Angular's config section:

```
    Highcharts.setOptions({
        global: {
            useUTC: true
        }
    });
```